# What is the difference between electricals and electronic?

Tags: electric-circuits, terminology, electronics

In the case of circuits, we generally mention two types of circuits one is the electric circuit and another one is the electronic circuit.  What is the basic difference?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: In my experience, when we say "electric ..." we are talking about something that uses electric _power_, and when we say "electronic ..." we are talking about something that generates, processes, or uses electronic _signals_.  I.e., any use of electricity to transmit or process any kind of _information_.

Comment: No @james large that is incorrect. The best answer so far is given by JF'r A Mhrzz

Comment: Not technically _incorrect_, unless you know more about my experience than I know.  But words change meaning from time to time, from place to place, and from vocation to vocation.  The books on my shelf are thirty to fifty years old, I am not a physicist by vocation, and my home is a long way from Catalonia.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference, at least in my native language (Catalan), is that electronics (*electrònics*) includes just the electrical (*elèctric*) components that are **static** and that are able to **control the electrons flow**.

The main aim of an electronic system is to process the information or the energy associated to the electronic signs.

Source: *INTRODUCCIÓ ALS SISTEMES ELECTRÒNICS, Emili Lupon*

Answer (score 1):

simply saying electric circuits basically contains resistors, capacitors inductors..generally the passive elements, on the other hand electronic circuits contains the active devices which could show analog or digital behavior like transistors for example.